# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping - AutoMapper

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, automapper

I am trying to map an Entity Framework Code First class to a WCF DataContract class using AutoMapper.

The code is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}

public class User1
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}

public static T Get<T>(this object source) where T : class
{
    Mapper.CreateMap(source.GetType(), typeof(T));
    T destination = default(T);
    Mapper.Map(source, destination);
    return destination;
}

User user = new User();
User1 user1 = user.Get<User1>();
```

I am getting this exception while executing the last line in above code:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Object -> User
>   System.Object -> DataLayer.User
>
> Destination path: User
>
> Source value: Service.User

Can anyone help in getting this resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.*

*Mapping types: Object -> User*

This is because you are passing a value of type `object`, creating a mapping from the underlying type `User` to type `User1`, then passing in the object as the source, for which no mapping exists (and the actual error message from the code provided would reference `User1` rather than `User`)

You can just use the overload of Map which allows you to tell AutoMapper what type to use:

```
Mapper.Map(source, destination, source.GetType(), typeof(T));
```

Or, if your code allows, use the overload of Map which which allows you to tell AutoMapper what type to use, and also to create the destination object itself:

```
 return (T)Mapper.Map(source, source.GetType(), typeof(T));
```

You may want to consider only creating the mapping if required, which would look like this:

```
public static T Get<T>(this object source)
{
    if (Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(source.GetType(), typeof (T)) == null)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap(source.GetType(), typeof (T));
    }

    return (T)Mapper.Map(source, source.GetType(), typeof(T));
}
```